# Can I enable "Find Declaration" whilst debugging in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

At my office we are using Delphi 7.
I notice that in Delphi the "Find Declaration" option doesn't appear in the context menu whilst debugging.
When I forcably invoke the method (by extending the IDE) I receive the exception "Browser is not available while debugging" in "TBrowser.EnsureBrowserSymbols" (in delphipro70.bpl).
Is there a way to make this function available whilst debugging? Perhaps through an extension or a configuration option I am missing?
I am currently having to grep search my entire solution each time.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: In a word, no. The functionality is simply not available while debugging. And yes, it is a shame. I have been bitten by this several times over the years. I wish it existed. Feel free to file a feature request with Embarcadero using [Quality Portal](http://quality.embarcadero.com).

Comment: I use Delphi 10.1 and it is available while debugging in that version (in context menu Find|Find declaration of... or CTRL + Mouseclick). So I think a function request would be pointless - Embarcadero won't offer a retrospective update.

Comment: Not all items in D10.1 will go to their declarations, this afternoon while debugging TPngImage would go it's declaration, but TBitmap wouldn't.

Comment: Although this would be a great debugging feature, I use two workarounds and don't miss the feature any more: (1) copy the symbol or method then search for it (while debugging) or (2) stop debugging, find declaration, restart debugging.